# Scale disconnected faces by moving Individual Origin

Tags: mesh, edit-mode

I have a sparse mesh with a bunch of disconnected faces I want to quickly bring together, I know there's an option in both Object Mode and UV Editor to scale objects/uv_island by moving their Individual Origin

Is there any similar option or addon for Edit Mode?

[image]

Comment: maybe an addon but I don't think you can do it with the default tools, you could separate by loose parts to make each mesh a separate object though

Comment: Just what I did, but was thinking I've missed something as every other tool seems to have this kind of functionality

Comment: in your situation maybe you could scale up all your meshes with the Individual Origin option selected in the Transform Pivot Point panel, it will bring the meshes close together, then switch back to Median Point and scale down the whole thing